# Using promises with modular JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, deferred, modular

I am trying to apply the modular JS pattern in my code, but am having a hard time implementing promises. I am used to to promises in 1 line using "then", but now I have separate functions and each one is calling the server and returning a value to the other function, I don't know how I can do this. I am confused how I can use done & resolve at the same time.

Here's my code below:

```
   //I want to call a function, makeLinksObject(), which will call the another function that calls the server
   var formattedObject = makeLinksObject();
   formattedObject.done(function (renderedObject) {
            render(renderObject);
                    })

  function makeLinksObject() {
            //here I want to call another function that will call the server
            var dfd = getLastTimeUpdated();
            var linksArray = [];
            var linksObject = {};
            //get site updated date
            dfd.done(function (dateUpdated) {
                $.each(links, function (index, value) {
                    var linkObject = {};
                    obj.Title = value.Title.toLowerCase();
                    linksArray.push(obj);
                });

                linksObject = {
                    lblcallerId: "some value here"
                    links: linksArray
                }

            }); // end done

            return dfd.resolve(linksObject);
        }
        function getLastTimeUpdated() {
            var modificationUrl = "serverurl"
            dfd = $.ajax({
                url: modificationUrl,
                method: "GET",
                headers: {
                    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
                }
            });
            dfd.done(function(data){
                dfd.resolve(data.d.LastItemModified);
            })

               return dfd.promise(); 

        }
```

How do I return the value from server from function 3, to be used in function 2, and the result of function 2, to be used in function 1, then I can draw my html in function 1.

Currently, I am having an error in the second function and it's not recognizing my deferred object.

I thought about writing code that will have nested then, then, but I want to use modular code to make my code organized. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: these a jQuery promises which are not promise/A+ promises ... regardless, you seem to not understand how jQuery promises work ... you assign $.Deferred() to dfd, then the next line, you assign something else ... ergo, the first assignment is pointless ... next ... .done in jQuery promise land is sort of like .then ... which means that the promise has been resolved ... but you try to resolve it again using dfd.resolve .. I think I said all this before, then you deleted the question!

Comment: `$.Deferred()` is not necessary. `$.ajax()` returns a jQuery promise object. What is the expected order of function calls?

Comment: @JaromandaX, thanks for your comment. I have removed the first declaration from my code for the deferred. I know that done acts like then, but done specifies success on a separate function, but then gives u the success as one of it's arguments. However, I am not able to get around all of this with multiple functions like my case

Comment: here's how your code should be written - https://jsfiddle.net/jaromanda/471y1r64/2/ - note, edited to remove unused variable

Comment: Thank you for your example, but when do I use resolve???

Comment: I thought resolve would make me get rid of the nested then

Comment: your use of resolve is incorrect ... value returned from `.then` is a promise ... there is no nested then

Comment: so when do I use resolve? from my understanding, I should use it when the request is successful to return back the item from the server

Comment: $.ajax returns a promise that is resolved when the request succeeds ... you dont' call resolve anywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$.ajax()` returns a jQuery promise object, `$.Deferred()` is not necessary and can be removed; substitute `.then()` for `.done()` where you want to return a value other than the original promise value returned from `$.ajax()`, use `return` within function calls and `.then()`. Note, you could also include error handling to the pattern by chaining `.fail()` to then last `.then()` in each chain

```
   var formattedObject = makeLinksObject();

   formattedObject
   .done(function(renderedObject) {
     render(renderObject);
   })

   function makeLinksObject() {
     var dfd = getLastTimeUpdated();
     var linksArray = [];
     var linksObject = {};

     return dfd.then(function(dateUpdated) {
       $.each(links, function(index, value) {
         var linkObject = {};
         obj.Title = value.Title.toLowerCase();
         linksArray.push(obj);
       });

       linksObject = {
         lblcallerId: "some value here",
         links: linksArray
       }

     })
     .then(function() {
       return linksObject
     });
   }

   function getLastTimeUpdated() {
     var modificationUrl = "serverurl"
     return $.ajax({
       url: modificationUrl,
       method: "GET",
       headers: {
         "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
       }
     })
     .then(function(data) {
       return data.d.LastItemModified;
     })

   }
```